# Django: Error: ImproperlyConfigured Module does not define a " " class

Tags: django, django-middleware

ImproperlyConfigured: Middleware module "report" does not define a "ReportMiddleware" class

But I had defined this, but probably defined in wrong place, so where should I place this class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put it within the module in the package as specified in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.

Comment: Yes, I did this in settings.py

Comment: That's nice. Is it in the module in the package specified?

Comment: Found the issue, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 16):

Today I had the same error. It was due to confusing (at least for me) naming scheme.

If you specify your middleware like so:

```
'yourapp.SomeMiddleware'
```

in your settings.py and put your SomeMiddleware class definition in SomeMiddleware.py in your application directiory your project will break. In this case settings.py should read:

```
'yourapp.SomeMiddleware.SomeMiddleware'
```

a better method would be to use a common yourapp/middleware.py for all middleware definitions and use it like django.contrib middlewares do, in which case your seetings.py should include:

```
'yourapp.middleware.SomeMiddleware'
```